# What is good tool to make a new table inside access?

Tags: ms-access

I am looking a way to process huge access tables, make complex analytic calculation based on its contents and next create a new resulting table.

What tools are here to play with it?  Will it be enough Access VBA or Visual Studio Express?

Answer (score 0):

Use the query design window in MS Access if this is not a coded solution just analysis. Access is particularly strong for quickly creating quite complex queries and switching between select and make table.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/add-or-remove-a-table-or-query-in-the-query-design-grid-mdb-HP005187982.aspx

Comment: Yes, I using it now, but it has limitations on field length, so when my analytic function becoming more then 15 rows in height it forbids to write more.

Comment: Please post the sample query sql.

Comment: the field function looks like Switch([field1]="1" and Right([field2],1)="8" and [field3]<>"2"; "id1"; [field1]="1" and Right([field2],1)="8" and [field3]="2";"id2"; [field1]="2" and Left([field2],2)="15" and [field3]="1"; "id3"; ... and so on for 10 more lines ... ;1=1;"something missed")

Comment: The above can be greatly simplified. The various limits can be seen here : http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2006/06/05/access-2007-limits.aspx

Comment: It can not be simplified. If making artificial columns with intermediate results then query becomes unreadable.

Comment: I was not suggesting intermediate columns, I was suggesting lookup tables and joins, or at the very least, derived tables.

Comment: Field values varied too much. Full lookup table can have size about 300 cells, then checking it all right and updating it for temporary needs can be too huge task. Masks or some kind of it in switch function is lot more easier to check and update.

Comment: From looking at the field function above l was wondering if it is worth writing a custom function in VBA.   Then calling that custom function see - http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/creating-and-using-user-defined-functions-in-access/

Comment: User defined functions are slow and difficult to build further queries from, but nearly anything would be better than that sample statement.